# What bytestring produces "X" on unary negation?

Tags: javascript, python, bit-manipulation, byte

I would like to do something like this:

```
~b"???"
```

Which produces `b"X"`. How would I find out the byte-sequence to use? Any language is fine, so tagging with python+js.

Comment: look up the UTF code for "X" and negate it? Is that the question?

Comment: like `"X".charCodeAt(0)`

Comment: @Pointy so that would be `88` -> `-89`. How would I write that as a byte-string though? `~ord('X')` --> `-89`

Comment: What do you mean by "byte string"?

Comment: @Pointy in python I'd write it as `b'\x01\x02'`...

Comment: How long is the byte sequence? Or just any length?

Comment: Python bytestrings don't support the `~` operator in the first place.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this in the first place? Your underlying goal will determine the best way to handle this, because what you're literally asking for doesn't make sense.

Comment: Write the output of a test from a SQL engine. I'm just using python (or any language really, I tagged js as well) to see what the code is.

Comment: That still doesn't make sense. What are you doing with SQL, and how does that connect to using the `~` operator on types that don't support it?

Comment: @user2357112 inverting bytes is a common operation, no? https://gyazo.com/a7a56d3e86f3c8246f040d002fa3601e

Comment: @David542: What database engine is that? It looks like it's inverting the bits of your bytestring to produce a different bytestring, then base64 encoding the result for display. Neither Javascript nor Python will do that if you try `~b'X'` (it's a syntax error in Javascript and a type error in Python), and it's completely different from what the answer you accepted does.

Comment: @user2357112 I'm testing it in BigQuery, but also in Postgres it does the same (though it displays it as a number)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with XOR operations. Here's an example in Python:

```py
def invert_byte_seq(seq):
    if isinstance(seq, str):
        seq = bytes(seq, 'utf-8')
     
    ret_str = ''.join([chr(byte ^ 0x7F) for byte in seq])
    return bytes(ret_str, 'utf-8'), ret_str
     

>>> invert_byte_seq('???')
    (b'@@@', '@@@')
```

Then to test we can swap 'X' twice and should get the same thing back:

```py
>>> byte_str, _ = invert_byte_seq('X')
>>> invert_byte_seq(byte_str)[1]
    'X'
```

I changed 0xFF to 0x7F to better represent the ASCII table. You can change that value to correspond to your encoding.

Comment: @David542: Are you sure? Did you test it against your SQL output? It looks to me like it's doing something completely different from what you need.

Comment: @user2357112 right, yea that doesn't seem to work in the case I'm looking for.

Comment: @David542 so then what's an example of input/output you're expecting? Based on your initial example this does what you asked.